# Cytoscape.js and loading data in subscribe

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js

So I am a little confused and maybe someone can shed some light on my issue. I am exploring using Cytoscape. Neat library.

My issue is adding elements to the graph. In the image below if I add to my elements array (circle at top) if will display that node fine. However, if I pull it into a subscribe (circle at bottom) it will not display. The data I am adding in each location is the same.

Why will it not load the node to the graph if it is inside a subscribe? My intention is to call my service to get my points and load the necessary elements. Nothing extreme.

I am using the cytoscape.js library inside an Angular project. Thanks.

```
 GetServices() { 
      this.elements = [];
    // this.elements.push({data: { id: 'a', name: 'Zone 1' }, position: { x: 100, y: 200 }})
    // this.BuildCy();
    const services: Observable<any>[] = [];
    services.push(this.someservice.GetSomeMethod());

    forkJoin(services).subscribe((response) => { 

        this.elements.push({data: { id: 'a', name: 'Zone 1' }, position: { x: 100, y: 200 }})
        this.BuildCy();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) only emits if the source observables complete. If not, you could try to use [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) function with a piped in [`take(1)`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take) operator. It will complete after the first emission.

```js
combineLatest(services).pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This didn't work though. I would need the source to complete which is why I am using forkjoin. It would be the dataset for all my points.

Comment: @GlitchEclipse: Then you need to show what is returned from the `GetConfigPointDetailsByPoint()` function. Also please try to post the code as text, screenshots make it harder to reproduce.

Comment: I update it as a code block, but your missing the question. It doesn't matter what the subscribe returns in my example because  I am directly pushing a value inside the subscribe. The same two lines commented at the top before the subscribe work. Once they are inside the subscribe they don't. The elements array has a value before the chart is built.

Comment: No you're missing the issue. The first two lines work because you're pushing items directly. The subscription doesn't work because presumable the subscription isn't even being hit. You need to check if the observable returned from the service actually returns a proper response or if it returns an error. Try to subscribe to a single observable first with an error callback and see if the response is returned correctly.

Comment: It subscription is being hit and doesn't return an error on the response. I think the graph is loading before the response is finished so the element data is not in the array when the graph is loaded.

Comment: Like I said you need to show more data, how is the graph built, where is it built? What is the nature of the observables, is it a stream or does it emit only one notification an complete? Without more information we can't proceed.